# How to choose another ruby/gem environment in Aptana?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, aptana

I would like to use a non-default ruby interpreter and gem environment with the Aptana Studio3 Application. I use it on a Linux system without root permissions. I also cannot configure my login `PATH`, as described on the setup page (http://www.aptana.com/downloads/start). Therefore, I would like to make use of the second possibility proposed on the setup page:

> If getting your login PATH set up in this way isn't practical for you, you can work around the problem by launching Aptana Studio 3 from the command line, using the studio3 command line utility. This utility can be found at the top level of the Aptana Studio 3 installation folder, so you can put that folder in your PATH for convenience. (The command line utility can also be called after Aptana Studio 3 is running, to get it to open source code files for editing.)

As I don't find the `studio3` command line utility at the top level of my installation folder (I downloaded the zip File `Aptana_Studio_3_Setup_Linux_x86_3.3.1.zip`) I would appreciate help in how to make use of this studio3 command line utility. Where do I find it? How do I configure the ruby/gem environment?